# Does clearing Chrome appdata delete all the currently opened tabs?

Tags: insufficient-memory, chrome-for-android, cache

My phone has a low memory problem, so I have to periodically clear the app data of some apps which makes them act like I just installed it.

Currently I have many open tabs (100+) in my Chrome Browser. If I clear the app data will it delete all the tabs currently opened in my browser? If it does, is there any other way to save all the tabs to my Google Account?

Comment: I don't really see or how exactly do you think deleting cache files, that will recreate in a few minutes again, will save you "memory".

Comment: @xangua He didn't say cache though.

Comment: It is one of the tags.

Answer (score 1):

Clearing the "App Data" will definitely close all opened tabs.
It will also delete the history of the app, so there will be no way to reopen the previously opened tabs. There is no way to save all the tabs, since this is part of the "History".

Answer (score 1):

**Note:** *this is a partial answer meant to address only specific part of the question.*

---

> If I clear the app data will it delete all the tabs currently opened in my browser?

The state and relevant information of tabs such as the list of URLs opened through those tabs are saved inside `/data/data/com.android.chrome/app_tabs`. When you would  clear Chrome's data using Settings app, everything under the private data directory of Chrome (`/data/data/com.android.chrome`) would be deleted, so, yes, your opened tabs would be lost and as Victor Ivanov noted, the history would also be deleted.

Answer (score 0):

If you share those websites tabs to email you can launch email after clearing your chrome data and relaunch those websites. You won't lose them.

Notice chrome has three vertical dots on the top right corner of the browser..  Click it.   Scroll down until you see share. You have many choices of where to share your chrome tabs.   You can share to any or many of the choices.

First,  click on the first tab you want to save. Then select the vertical dots.  Scroll down until you see share.   Click email or note pad,  whatever retrieval system works best for you.  Select it.   The program launches either with the saved URL or information if you've actually selected specific information.  I like to use email because I can find the information on all platforms (phone, computer,  tablet).  Send yourself an e-mail..

Repeat steps for each tab you want to save.

When you are done clearing chrome data,  log into your email.   Select your emailed tab email.   Open it and launch.   Save your tabs.

Comment: Note that this only saves the current URL of each tab. It does not retain the browser session, nor even the tab's history breadcrumbs.